# How to switch wifi channel without dropping connection?

Tags: linux, wifi, embedded

We are developing small internet connected device that connects via wifi and does some work. It is controlled via mobile app.

For configuration purposes we use wi-fi module that can work in both STA + AP modes simultaneously via two interfaces wlan0 and wlan1. One of the interfaces works in Master mode. Phone connects to the device via wlan1 and sends command for the device to connect to another network and waits for result. Device in turn connects to another wi-fi network using wlan0 and notifies the phone if connection was successful or not.

But there is one issue. Both interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1) must work on the same channel as we have single hardware module. This causes channel of wlan1 to change in order to match of channel for wlan0.

Here comes the problem. When channel changes phone looses connection with the device. **Is there a way to change wi-fi channel but keep connection between the device and mobile phone?**

Our wi-fi module is rtl8723bu.
Linux 3.4.103.
Wifi daemons: hostapd v0.8.x_rtw_r7475.20130812_beta, wpa_supplicant v2.3.

Comment: This question has a good quality, if you vote to close, please vote for migrate this to unix SE.